# how to use hibernate versioning in bidirectional association Spring data JPA?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data

Lets say I have bidirectional one-to-many association between Parent-Child, mapped as follows:

TradingAccount.java

```
public class TradingAccount {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "tradingAccount", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
  private List<UnderlyingPerTradingAccount> underlyingPerTradingAccounts;
  @Version
  private Long version;
}
```

UnderlyingPerTradingAccount.java

```
public class UnderlyingPerTradingAccount {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;
  @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST})
  private TradingAccount tradingAccount;
  private Boolean enableBuy;
  private Boolean enableSell;
}
```

this code work, but the problem after saving or updating Trading Account I found new three trading account in the database (primary key + null in all other columns)

Comment: You shouldn't use the cascade option at both sides of your relationship, especially not in Parent-Child-Relationships like this. https://dzone.com/articles/beginner%E2%80%99s-guide-jpa-and

Comment: i got this exception: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing

Comment: You probably save the ``UnderlyingPerTradingAccount ``with a reference to a unpersisted ``TradingAccount``? When the TradingAccount is the parent, you must save only that entity, not the ``UnderlyingPerTradingAccount``, even when you edit only the ``UnderlyingPerTradingAccount``.